# TLS termination on Google Compute Engine

Tags: ssl, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, google-cloud-http-load-balancer

I'm trying to set up a TLS termination proxy (a.k.a load balancer) for my GCE instance. However it doesn't seem to work when I follow the [documentations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/).

Is there any step by step guide on how to do this? Has anyone actually done this before?

Answer (score 0):

A HTTPS target proxy accepts only TLS 1.0 and up when terminating client SSL requests. It speaks only TLS 1.0 and up to the backend service when the backend protocol is HTTPS. You can follow this step by step [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/tcp-ssl/#setting_up_ssl_load_balancing) on how to set up Google Cloud Load Balancing with SSL proxy.